# MySQL TIMESTAMP being stored as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 only in RDS?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, amazon-rds

I have a CodeIgniter application with the timezone set at gmt in the config.php file.

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

I notice two things:

1. My local database sets a TIMESTAMP in the database but not to GMT even though I have explicitly set it. Why is that?
2. My production Amazon RDS database sets all TIMESTAMPS to 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Why is that?

Remember, I am not explicitly passing a time reference in any of my models. I have the table set to auto-insert the TIMESTAMP when a record is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

1. Timezone configuration in PHP and in MySQL are two different things. While you configure it to be as GMT in PHP, MySQL still considers it as a timestamp set in `/etc/my.cnf` file under `default-time-zone='timezone'` directive. You can retrieve current MySQL timezone configuration with this query:

   ```
   SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
   ```
2. This depends too much on the implementation. While you mention that you do not pass any time references, I am sure CodeIgniter does that for you in one way or another. You should show some code, as I doubt there is a bug like this in CodeIgniter, so you most likely set something wrong. **Update** this will most likely be hapening due to timezone differences. If you try to save a timestamp in the future, it will default to 0000-00-00...

Comment: OK, I ran your query in both my local machine and on RDS. My local machine returns SYSTEM for both and RDS returns UTC (which is what I want) for both. This at least explains my local machine issue but, why is RDS inserting it as 0s in the database?

Comment: The 0s are inserted when you provide an invalid timestamp. I would guess that you are trying to add timestamp, which database thinks is in the future (due to timezone differences), thus it writes 0. It always writes 0s when timestamp is invalid.

Comment: I am not actually passing any timestamp manually in the models. I have the table set such that it inserts the TIMESTAMP in the created_on column when a new record is inserted. My production server is in PST but I want UTC so it can't be in the future.

Comment: If you use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on INSERT and it fails to work, then this is clearly a DBA problem and I would look for information on DBA SE.

Comment: You're onto something. I just noticed that only my local database has it set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP but my RDS database did not have that property. I ran the same migrations to create the tables even on RDS. Wonder why it didn't set that property. Do you recommend that I write another migration to set it?

Comment: Rerun the migrations, I don't feel like I am in the position to judge if you should rewrite it or not, but the databases must have same definitions for you to debug this properly. At least it seems like you have found what was causing the issue.

Comment: How would the syntax to set default behavior for a column to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and on update to none look in MySQL? I'm not a MySQL expert (as you may have imagined).

Answer (score 1):

You need to either change field format or the inserting value.
Also you can find some mysql functions handy - CURDATE() or NOW () for example

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (NULL,:col1,:col2,,NOW())';
```

But personally I'd avoid mysql timestamps. they can be changed unexpectedly, ruining all your data. I'd use DATETIME and set all values manually.

Comment: Do you recommend I edit all my models to manually insert the date?

Comment: just place the now()/CURDATE() function in your code ! this will do it! test before ! don't do rogue on production ! kkk

Comment: so instead of solving the real problem here, we just rewrite software to introduce new different problems?

Comment: it might be problem true! is what he find more convinient ! this might not be the best approach !

Answer (score 0):

In your event form, you should send to the server a hidden input witch will contain client's timezone offset. You can get it via Javascript's Date.getTimezoneOffset() method (it gives you offset in minutes between UTC and users's local time).

If you can't do that, you can save user's local timezone into db or ask it in your event form.

Then, in your INSERT or UPDATE query, you can use DATE_ADD('2012-12-13 19:41:00', [user offset] MINUTE) to convert timestamp. You can also do it in php, or client-side when submitting form...

For example in PHP :

```
strtotime($event_date);
```

gives you the date's Unix timestamp (so, in seconds). To convert it into another timezone, according you get the offset in minutes with javascript method, you can do :

```
$dbTimestamp = strtotime($event_date) + $_POST['offsetInMinutes']/60;
```

If you get the offset in this form : '+2:00' or '-6:00', you can get offset in hours using a regular expression :

```
preg_match('/(.*)\:00/', '+2:00', $match)
```

will set '+2' into $match[1]

Another one:

First, set your master time reference to 'GMT' in your config file:

```
$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';
```

Choose from timezone reference in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/date_helper.html or use the timezone_menu() to set a variable or update a DB column for $timezone in the code below:

```
$time = now();  
$timezone = 'UM5';  
$daylight_saving = TRUE; // or FALSE  
$local_time = unix_to_human(gmt_to_local($time, $timezone, $daylight_saving));  
echo $local_time;
```

Comment: I'm not really storing the user's timezone and I don't need it either. My server returns it's local timezine which basically needs to be converted to UTC. Does CodeIgniter take the $config['time_zone'] reference when making database insertions? My database is already set to UTC.